# Select2 is not displaying the selected value

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using 4.0.0 full so that it supports 3.5.2 features too. I'm using `query` option to fill the results. Everything works fine, but when I select a item from the result it is not displaying it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".select").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        query: function (query) {
            if (query.term) {

                var data = { results: [] }, i, j, s;
                for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                    s = "";
                    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) { s = s + query.term; }
                    data.results.push({ id: query.term + i, text: s });
                }
                query.callback(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<select class="select" style="width:300px"></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with Select2 that is caused by how the adapters are being automatically generated. Because Select2 will only automatically create a new `<option>` for the array adapters (and anything building form them, like AJAX), anything not using it will not be able to generate new options on the fly. Unfortunately, the default [`query` decorator](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/bd46b7eaac38f62fc200194423a24394c450d071/src/js/select2/compat/query.js#L4) will wrap the [`SelectAdapter`](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/bd46b7eaac38f62fc200194423a24394c450d071/src/js/select2/data/array.js), which is not a subclass of the [`ArrayAdapter`](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/bd46b7eaac38f62fc200194423a24394c450d071/src/js/select2/data/select.js).

You can work around this by forcing the array adapter to be used, by passing in a blank array for `data`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".select").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        data: [],
        query: function (query) {
            if (query.term) {

                var data = { results: [] }, i, j, s;
                for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                    s = "";
                    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) { s = s + query.term; }
                    data.results.push({ id: query.term + i, text: s });
                }
                query.callback(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<select class="select" style="width:300px"></select>
```

This [should be reported as a bug](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#reporting-bugs-with-select2) to the [Select2 repository](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of messing around here is what I have come up with it works but there has got to be a better way of doing this surely.

I couldn't get any other of the option to work.

```
var is_ajax = false;

$("#select2Data").select2({
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
        return markup;
    },
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    //multiple:true,
    data: [],
    query: function(query) {

        var key = query.term;

        if (key) {

            $("#select2-select2Data-results li").show().filter(function() {
                return $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim().indexOf(key) == -1;
            }).hide();

        } else {

            Api.ajax({
                action: 'get_data'
            }).then(function(response) {

                var data = {
                    results: []
                };

                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {

                    data.results.push({
                        id: i,
                        text: response.data[i].Name
                    });

                }

                is_ajax = true;

                query.callback(data);

            });

        }

    }

}).on('change', function(e) {

    data = this.value;

});
```